# Editing lines (Photoshop / Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have a problem editing this image:

[image]

This is only a small part of the image zoomed in. The request is that the lines be the same width and not that wonky, if possible. These lines are on a separate layer in a .psd, but no vectors unfortunately.

Is there an automatic way to do this? Or at least a shortcut here and there so I don't have to draw the whole thing (it would take days and I'm doing it as a favor)?

What would be great is if there was an AI script or something that recognizes paths and creates them accordnigly, so I can just edit the Stroke width. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ..., I don' know how to do it in Photoshop, nor Illustrator, not it is a completely automated procedure, but it may save you some time still.

Find a raster-to-vector program, [WinTopo](http://wintopo.com/) is one of those, Autodesk has its own also (although I don't know whether they have a free version), convert the image from raster/image to vector drawing, import it into one vector graphics editing program (like Autocad, or anything that you can find really), and set the line width to what you prefer. After that, if you need it in that form, you export it in raster form (.gif for instance).

Of course all those raster-to-vector programs have automated features. You don't have to draw lines by hand. And from what your image looks like, it could be a pretty straightforward process.

Comment: Hi Rook, thanks for your response.

The raster-to-vector conversion isn't a problem, Illustrator has a built in feature which does exactly that.

The problem is, when it vectorizes the image, I can't edit the lines. After the vectorization those are shapes or fills, not strokes. That's why I asked the question about the AI script.

Comment: @Stefan T - Ah, then do try the approach with WinTopo or Autocad Raster Design (if you have access to it) - they will convert it to lines, which you can afterwards edit. This, if I can just mention it in passing, is a pretty common operation in CAD world. Think of all those old drawings which have to be digitalized. Btw, I don't know what Illustrator does, since I've never used it, but I can imagine. It doesn't convert it to true vector form (vectors=lines), but rather just "recognizes the areas".

Comment: I've done it in the end with Illustrator, it has an option to do what you explained for CAD. Thanks!